# Изменение размера рисунка

Tags: html, css, графика, веб-дизайн, photoshop

Есть рисунок (снимок из paint-а - png рисунок)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он вставляется полностью на сайте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как удалить ненужную белую свободную часть рисунка (в Paint-е и Photoshop-е, приведите обязательно в пэйнте, так как фотошоп у меня пока что не установлен) - как выделить нужную часть (типа Ctrl+A) и обрезать ненужную. Должно отображаться как на https://www.figma.com/file/noqP1gzhrAlGAErPNBgknp/test?node-id=1%3A783 (tablet версия).

Comment: обрежьте в том же paint photoshop gimp

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, это непросто, но попробую помочь.

1. Запустите программу Paint и откройте в ней ваше изображение.
2. Перейдите на вкладку "Главная" меню программы (в Windows 7 и выше; если у вас Windows 3.1, 95, 98, NT, 2000, Me или XP - там выглядит несколько иначе).
3. Найдите инструмент "Выделить" в секции "Изображение".
4. Поместите курсор мыши над ним и произведите одиночный клик левой кнопкой мыши (если мышь настроена под левшу, тогда правой).
5. Инструмент станет активным (будет выделен затемненным прямоугольником).
6. Поместите курсор мыши над одним из углов нужной вам области изображения и зажмите левую (в случае настройки для левшей - правую) кнопку мыши.
7. НЕ ОТПУСКАЯ кнопку, переместите курсор мыши до противоположного угла нужной вам области изображения. При этом данная область будет обведена пунктирной рамкой.
8. Отпустите кнопку мыши.
9. В секции "изображение" вкладки "Главная" меню программы "Paint" найдите инструмент "Обрезать", переместите курсор на него и произведите одинарный щелчок левой (в случае настройки для левшей - правой) кнопкой мыши.
10. Изображение станет обрезанным.
11. Нажмите пункт меню "Файл" и в нем выберите пункт "Сохранить", если вам нужно заменить ваше изображение обрезанным, или "Сохранить как", если вы желаете оставить первоначальную версию нетронутой.

Кстати, описанная мной (и спрашиваемая вами) процедура называется "Обрезка рисунка", а не "Изменение размера". Если вам нужно узнать подробнее про именно изменение размера (т.е., сделать из большого рисунка маленький или наоборот) - посмотрите обучающие материалы в сети, например, вот: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HJPdYACzeU